# Scroll to another page and open section

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem. I want to scroll from a page to another but a section must be checked directly after scrolling.

The first page is including a :

```
<a href="{% url 'userguide' %}#section7">                                                 
<p>Link1</p></a>
```

The second page is a type of vertical section :

```html
<div id="section7">
  <section id="section7">
    <input type="radio" name="sections" id="option7">
    <label for="option7">Text</label>
    <article>
      <div class="inner">
      </div>
    </article>
  </section>
</div>
```

After using this URL :

Link1

It scrolls to the section but doesn't open it.[image: Design]

My javascript:

```
var userguide = {
getURLParams(){
    let params = {}
    let q = window.location.search.substr(1).split('&');
    for (let x=0; x<q.length; x++){
        params[q[0].split('=')[0]] = q[0].split('=')[1];
    }
    return params
},

initScroll(){
    let sectionId = this.getURLParams()['section'];
    if (sectionId){
        let val = $(sectionId).closest("input")
        $val.checked();
    }
},
init(){

    this.initScroll();

}
}
```

Css for the vertical tabs:

```
 input[name="sections"]:checked ~ article {
 display: block;
   }
```

Comment: how is the open/close done? Via css or js? (without the clicking to another page aspect)

Comment: as css : input[name="sections"]:checked ~ article {
  display: block;
}
When the radio buttons is checked the text(as article) is displayed

Comment: `$(this).closest("input")` - what are you imagining `this` to be in this context …?

Comment: ohh!! it is wrong... it is the sectionId

Comment: Please I need your help

Comment: do you use a server-side language like PHP at all? Or is just pure js etc. ? only asking as looks twiggy

Comment: No it is not PHP.. Django framework but the function is pure javascript